# getting all the items of a simpledb domain in typica library 1.7

Tags: java, amazon-simpledb

in typica 1.7 there is no listItemsWithAttributes function in Domain class while this was available in earlier versions. How to get list of  items in a Domain using Typica 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Please see **selectItems** method of class com.xerox.amazonws.simpledb.Domain. You need to pass a query with an explicit list of attributes.

You can specify an explicit list of attributes (attribute1,..., attributeN) in SELECT query -

```
select attribute1,..., attributeN from <domain name>
```

Method -

```
public SDBListResult<Item> selectItems(String selectExpression,
                                   String nextToken,
                                   boolean consistent)
                            throws SDBException

Performs a query against this domain. A set of items is returned which may not be complete. If the nextToken in the result is set, this method can be called again with the same query and the supplied nextToken.

Parameters:
    selectExpression - the query to be run
    nextToken - an optional token to get more results
    consistent - if true, consistency is assured 
Throws:
    SDBException - wraps checked exceptions
```